# Share Current Image in ViewPager

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, android-glide

I am using Glide library https://github.com/bumptech/glide (alternative of Picasso) and follow this tutorial http://blog.grafixartist.com/image-gallery-app-android-studio-1-4-glide/
Basic features work well such as show images as GridView, slide images use gesture in ViewPager. But I want to add more action like sharing and saving a **current image in ViewPage**r, but I don't understand how to get curent position. I have tried adding Share function on activity like code below but nothing happen. I think I must put function on fragment. Maybe you can help me. Thanks.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    public ArrayList<ImageModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int pos;

    Toolbar toolbar;


    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        data = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");
        pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);


        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), data);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);


        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {




            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_share) {


            share();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void share() { //Nothing happen


        SubsamplingScaleImageView Imgv = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) mViewPager.findViewWithTag(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        //Imgv.setBackgroundResource(data.get(pos).getUrl());
        //Imgv.setTag(pos);
        Imgv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap icon = Imgv.getDrawingCache();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String nama = getPackageName().toString();
        String judul = getTitle().toString();


        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);

        String sAux = "I recommend " + (judul) + " for you:\n";
        sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+(nama);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser( shareIntent, "Share via"));

        startActivity(shareIntent);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ArrayList<ImageModel> data = new ArrayList<>();

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<ImageModel> data) {
            super(fm);
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position, data.get(position).getName(), data.get(position).getUrl());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return data.get(position).getName();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */

        String name, url;
        int pos;
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private static final String ARG_IMG_TITLE = "image_title";
        private static final String ARG_IMG_URL = "image_url";

        @Override
        public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
            super.setArguments(args);
            this.pos = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            this.name = args.getString(ARG_IMG_TITLE);
            this.url = args.getString(ARG_IMG_URL);
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, String name, String url) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            args.putString(ARG_IMG_TITLE, name);
            args.putString(ARG_IMG_URL, url);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

        }



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);


            final SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_image);

            final ImageView share = (ImageView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.share);
            share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { //This is just test code

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Image + " + pos , // This pos is works great
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });

            Glide
                    .with(getActivity())
                    .load(url)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .thumbnail(0.1f)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                            imageView .setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap)

                            );
                        }
                    });



            return rootView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is a `getCurrentItem()` method in the ViewPager class...

Comment: Hi zgc7009, how to implement it? I think my code was wrong